# Is it really the best practice to prefer C++ references to pointers in all situations?

Tags: c++

[C++ FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/references#refs-vs-ptrs) says:

***“Use references when you can, and pointers when you have to.”***

I feel it’s not as easy as stated above. The reasons why references are generally better to pointers have been well discussed. So I would rather like to discuss special cases where references make sense but are highly unusual and just don’t feel right:

To me the most obvious case is their usage in **general data structures** like a tree or linked-list. Their interfaces could be certainly implemented using references and feel safer, but I haven’t seen a single implementation that would take advantage of  references e.g.:

```
Node *parent = n.parent(); // parent might be unset -> pointer
Node &child = n.child(5); // child is always valid -> reference
```

Although it might seem attractive, it leads to code like this:

```
if(parent == &child) ... //  weird, unusual at least?
```

I’m wondering, is this what stands for pure C++?

Each time I’ve tried to blindly use references wherever it’s possible, I’ve encountered all kinds of similar **inconsistencies** and ended up **mixing pointers and references** in various ugly ways.

To conclude, why the **operator new** doesn’t return a reference to a new instance instead of a pointer in the first place? (and throws in case of error):

```
Node &n = new Node;
delete &n;
```

It’s an absurd example, but isn’t that what would be “pure C++”?

Comment: You're missing the point. Think of the quote as "use automatic storage when you can, and dynamic storage (`new`) when you have to."

Comment: Use whatever makes sense. Usually, that means pointers in the implementation of containers, and references in client code. Also, nobody can stop anyone from writing ridiculous code, so if someone says `delete &x;`, there's not much you can do. You have to assume that your clients *want* to write correct programs. You just have to make it easy for them.

Comment: References are preferred when passing objects to functions too because it is faster due to no copy constructor being invoked.

Comment: I think the FAQ is mainly referring to function arguments in this section.

Comment: I'm not sure that it gets any faster than passing a pointer.  There is no code that gets run (unless you're using a smart pointer wrapper class).

Comment: I don't always use a reference, But when I do its constant. Non constant references get confusing as later you don't know if the variable will be modified.

Comment: That is the google C++ style, over_optimistic.  It's what I prefer as well.

Comment: Technically const references can be const_cast<>ed, can't they? The point still holds though.

Comment: In fact, I personally tend to use references for object with value semantics (especially const references), and pointers for non-copyable huge objects and data structures. In that way I mix only values with references, and keep pointers aside. This feels consistent to me.

Comment: This seems as an ill posed question...

Comment: The title to this question is misleading. You say "in all situations", but that's *not* what the quote says. It says "where you can." These aren't even close to the same thing.

Comment: By "in all situations" I meant in all cases when you don't need null to indicate invalid objects, which to me is similar to "use pointers when you have to" as stated.

Comment: @FipS : Null is not for indicating invalid objects; use [Boost.Optional](http://www.boost.org/libs/optional/) for that.

Comment: Well, it's certainly an option, but a bit overkill when considering e.g. a tree node parent() getter.

Answer (score 13):

A reference cannot be modified to refer to a different object once it is initialized. But a pointer could be modified to refer different objects at run time.

**A general rule of thumb**

Whenever you want a variable to point to different objects during its life time, use a pointer.

If you just want to use a variable as an alias for another variable use a reference.

**As parameters**

We sometimes pass parameters as references (const/non-const). This would help in avoiding copying the entire object, every time a function is called. Hence this would make much sense, when passing object of large size.

If the function needs to receive some parameter than can optionally be null, you could use a pointer. But, again, you could always define a static null object for any class, and it can be used.

**As return values**

Whenever we overload operators such as [] or <<, we would return references. It is because, if I say, vec[0] = 10, it should actually assign the value 10 to position 0 in vec. Here I could not not use pointer for obvious reasons. *vec[0] = 10 won't just look nice. Also, you should guarantee, when you are returning a reference it is always referring to an object (It should never be null).

Again, when the function can return NULL values, use a pointer, otherwise you may have to declare a static null object for that class.

**As data members**

References should be initialized in the constructor. Hence, they cannot be changed once the object is constructed.

Hence if you need a variable that needs to point to different objects during the lifetime of the class, a pointer would be a good choice.

Comment: +1 welcome to SO and congratulations to a quite good debut ;)

Answer (score 6):

I think generic data structures fall under the "use pointers when you have to" clause.  That is, since references are constant (i.e. they always refer to the same object), using references in your linked list or tree node structure would mean that you couldn't insert new nodes or remove old ones from the data structure--generally defeating the purpose.

As somebody said in the comments, I think that advice really applies to function arguments.  Passing references rather than pointers avoids having to add null-pointer handling logic to every function, which brings a host of benefits in terms of code size and clarity.

Comment: In the case of a tree node, you can technically use references in the interface and still insert and remove nodes through manipulating internal representation that uses pointer. That would be a bit weird, but still possible. Otherwise I agree, that in the context of function arguments references make most sense.

Comment: Having reference data members has this habit of causing problems for any type that needs to be treated with value semantics, e.g. copied.

Comment: Yes, and when you use pointer data members instead of references to allow copy semantics. The question is whether stick with pointers even in the interface or expose the pointers as references. I would personally stick with pointers but I suspect that the recommendation as sated is to use references in this case.

Answer (score 1):

If you are familiar with NULL and NOT NULL columns in a relational database, or with the difference between a mandatory and an optional element in XSD, you may be able to draw a useful parallel from such a domain to guide you.

References would stand for variables that are fixed, standalone and not nullable.  Pointers for those you have a real need sometimes to pass "no value", or where you have a clear need to perform pointer arithmetic (such as with an array).  These are by no means the only differences, but most of the different syntax just follows from there.

To recap: reference = NOT NULL and read only.  Pointer = flexible and a bit more dangerous.

Answer (score -5):

The "new" operator allocates memory (just like malloc in C). Because C++ does not have a garbage collector implemented (like Java or C#) you can run out of memory. Therefore, when new  fails to allocate memory returns a NULL value. This way you can test if the allocation was successful.

You cannot use a reference with the new operator because of the possibility of assigning the NULL value caused by the lack of memory.

Comment: *Because C++ does not have a garbage collector implemented (like Java or C#) you can run out of memory* [Implying Java can't run out of memory?](http://www.google.com.au/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ie=UTF-8&ion=1#hl=en&sugexp=frgbld&gs_nf=1&cp=14&gs_id=2&xhr=t&q=java.lang.outofmemoryerror&pf=p&output=search&sclient=psy-ab&oq=java.lang.outo&aq=0&aqi=g4&aql=&gs_sm=&gs_upl=&gs_l=&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.,cf.osb&fp=9ac572733e1be876&biw=1920&bih=979&ion=1)

Comment: `new` doesn't return NULL, it throws an exception.

Comment: `new` does not return NULL, it throws `std::bad_alloc`. To make `new` return NULL on allocation failure you need to call it with the `std::nothrow` parameter.

Comment: And even if `new` did return `NULL` (as was once the case), the OP specifically asked how come it doesn't return a reference "and throws in case of error".